# Why is this Data Explorer query timing out and/or triggering a "Something is wrong with the server" alert?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I attempted to run the following query to find posts that are "signed" (ending) with the poster's username:

```
select top 5 posts.Id as [Post Link] from posts
join users on posts.OwnerUserId=users.id
where posts.body like '%' + users.displayname
```

In Firefox 7.0.1, the query takes a couple minutes, then the page displays:

> Error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

In Chrome 14.0.835.202, the query also takes a couple minutes, then displays a JavaScript alert box reading:

> Something is wrong with the server!

In both browsers, I never see any results displayed.

I was able to get the query to work by appending  `+ '%'` to the last line ([see the modified query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1964/posts-containing-the-posters-displayname)). However, this isn't what I originally intended-- I wanted to search only for posts that *end with* the user's display name, not for posts that merely *contain* the user's display name.

Comment: The error message appears to tell you everything you need to know: there is a query timeout that you've reached. I guess SQL Server doesn't do "Ends With" very well at all.

Answer (score 3):

You already found out that `like '%last word'` is slow and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394276/sql-best-way-to-compare-the-end-of-a-string-use-right-like-or-other) gives some hints on how these kind of queries can be improved.

I'm not sure if the body contained the same data it contains now but I expect your query would never returns any rows simply because no rows would match (which explains your timeouts). The body field contains the html markup and a lot of the content I inspected ended with an end tag for a paragraph: `</p>` and a not at first glance noticeable char(10).

`where body like '%'+displayname+'</p>'+char(10)` would still suffer from the same performance penalty (500 rows returned in 24157 ms) but the charindex variant was not much better...

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201930/posts-that-end-with-the-displayname-of-the-user) would give you the questions that needs an edit to get the name of the user removed:

```
select top 500 
       posts.Id as [Post Link] 
       , right(body,10)
       , ascii(right(body,1))
from 
       posts
join 
       users 
       on posts.OwnerUserId=users.id
where 
       body like '%'+ displayname+ N'</p>'+char(10)
and    posttypeid =1 -- questions
```

I left the debug columns in case you need to investigate cornercases that get skipped in error.